# how to handle a problematic previous advisor?

Tags: research-process

Luckily I got in academia after having a serious conflict with my previous advisor.  The problem was that he gave my dissertation proposal to his previous student (another his previous student said that he loved her a lot).  She even got $100,000 NSF grant with the proposal.

I said it was unfair.  Then he did his best to kick me out of the school (he even called the police for the reason I was shown up in his office; contacted all people to say that I am not qualified for a Ph.D. and so should be kicked out).

A school dean saved me and so I graduated. However, for the conflict, I couldn't get in my field (I am in totally different field); still I need to take medicine to get in a sleep, to meet people and to control my anger.

Anyway, I'd like to go back to my own field again because it is too tough to struggle in a new field.  Any advise?  Also I'd really like to pay all back to him regarding what he did to me.  What could be the best way?

Anyway, he is a full professor in a well-known research school; also he is a big name and so about 30% of faculties in this field are his previous students & 50% of senior faculties are his good friends.

Comment: What are you asking? If it's "how do I get revenge on my former advisor" then you likely won't get the answers you're looking for here.

Comment: Are there other people in your field who know that he’s a jerk?

Comment: Another previous student had a similar problem as I heard.  However, he became a good friend with all the other senior faculties and so he was well-proteced.

Comment: They say: "revenge is a dish best served cold". I say: Revenge is a dish left over, which you first put in the refrigerator. Then, thinking twice, you move it into the freezer. There it stays for a few years. And then, you clean it out and throw it away, because you will really regret it if you actually eat it. Vinegar will not get better with age, but it never was wine in the first place. As for the constructive part of your question: It is not a good step to "flee" a field and then return. Better to see if you can combine your expertise in the new field with the old - making yourself unique.

Comment: It is very interesting that all of the users put on hold are faculties.  Hopefully  my posting does not make you uncomfortable for the reason you are faculties having students like me.

Comment: `I'd like to go back to my own field again`. If that's what you like and want, go ahead and do it. Stop thinking about that person. He is not a god. You can make your own way. It will be hard at the beginning, but try to publish a paper even as a single author. Then, people can trust your abilities and start working with you.

Answer (score 6):

Get on with your life. Best way to get revenge would be for you to become successful and renowned in your field despite conflict with previous advisor.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a very egocentric MS advisor who stole my work. However, I got the MS thesis published against the odds. Do you have data from your previous work that is publishable? If so, go ahead and publish them. What are you working on right now? Is it something you like better than what your did earlier? If so, focus on what it matters now. Getting a stranglehold of your new research discipline and getting things published will be the best form of "revenge."

Comment: I am in statistics - no data at all. We just propose and prove what we propose.  anyways, thanks for your advice.